# How can I find a sentence with all the words using Regex?

Tags: php, regex

My sentence:
    **Hello world. I am a dog.**

I am using a search box and I want to replicate Google's autocomplete. As the user inputs words, the matching characters are selected. I want to match all sentences that contain ALL the words regardless of order. So for example..

**These keywords would match "Hello world. I am a dog."**

```
hello
dog
hello dog
i dog world hello
world dog am
```

Comment: "Hello, yes this is dog"

Comment: I'm not sure if it's some like this what you're looking for `/hello|dog|world|am/i`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression for this. Actually, I don't see how you could use a regular expression for this.

Tokenize the line by `explode(" ", $line);` and then see if all the words match.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB, so I want to keep everything in the SQL. If it isn't possible using regular expression, how does Google do it?

Comment: @user1426594 Google uses a _very_ complex algorithm that gets changed often.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could use lookahead assertions.

An example for "hello dog":

```
^(?=.*dog)(?=.*hello).*$
```

and for "i dog world hello":

```
^(?=.*i)(?=.*dog)(?=.*world)(?=.*hello).*$
```

and so on.